Error: weightoffont(uifont*) crash on Production build only
I currently have an app in TestFlight on apple for beta testing, but being my first time, I'm experiencing difficulty in troubleshooting crashes that are occurring.
When I test it in a simulator and on my phone via Expo Go, there's nothing wrong and it's just crashing while in a production build.
On one crash report I believe the thread that crashed was the following:
Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190771038 CF_IS_OBJC + 24 (CFRuntime.c:472)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001907711dc CFStringGetLength + 148 (CFString.c:2484)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001907c81dc CFStringFind + 60 (CFString.c:4495)
3   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104be1bf0 weightOfFont(UIFont*) + 212 (RCTFont.mm:60)
4   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104be16e4 +[RCTFont updateFont:withFamily:size:weight:style:variant:scaleMultiplier:] + 1788 (RCTFont.mm:477)
5   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d7cd30 -[RCTTextAttributes effectiveFont] + 128 (RCTTextAttributes.mm:220)
6   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d7c910 -[RCTTextAttributes effectiveTextAttributes] + 64 (RCTTextAttributes.mm:150)
7   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d78b60 -[RCTBaseTextShadowView attributedTextWithBaseTextAttributes:] + 472 (RCTBaseTextShadowView.mm:101)
8   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d78bd8 -[RCTBaseTextShadowView attributedTextWithBaseTextAttributes:] + 592 (RCTBaseTextShadowView.mm:111)
9   Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d7e740 -[RCTTextShadowView attributedTextWithMeasuredAttachmentsThatFitSize:] + 80 (RCTTextShadowView.mm:179)
10  Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d7eac0 -[RCTTextShadowView textStorageAndLayoutManagerThatFitsSize:exclusiveOwnership:] + 312 (RCTTextShadowView.mm:227)
11  Pumpzoid                        0x0000000104d7db34 RCTTextShadowViewMeasure(YGNode const*, float, YGMeasureMode, float, YGMeasureMode) + 132 (RCTTextShadowView.mm:385)

Specifically where the weightOfFont(UIFont*) + 212 (RCTFont.mm:60) is occuring.
At first glance this tells me that I need to check where I'm using fontWeights, so I do and there's nothing out of ordinary with how I use them. The error isn't exactly descriptive so if anyone can provide insight I'd appreciate it!
Update #1: Actually looking through five different crash reports, it seems that weightOfFont... is the cause of each crash.
Update #2: More steps that I've taken to potentially fix it, but haven't:

Rename the Fonts folder to font. One different post mentioned it had worked for them.
Add the following to my app.json:  "assetBundlePatterns": [ "assets/*" ],
Ran npx expo-doctor@latest to make sure everything worked, and it there's no errors or warnings.
A different post said to try to do use this to link your assets npx react-native-asset 
I've also created a react-native.config.js where I put module.exports = { assets: ['./assets/font'], };

Update #3: More steps that I've taken to potentially fix it, but haven't:

I came to potentially believe that I might be loading my fonts incorrectly, and when I swap between screens it might not be properly reloading (granted I was under the assumption once the app loads, I wouldn't have to worry about if the fonts are loaded.) I altered my font's loading to the following: (


    try {
                Font.loadAsync({
                    'RobotoSlab-Medium': require('./assets/font/RobotoSlab-Medium.ttf'),
                    'RobotoSlab-Bold': require('./assets/font/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf')
                }).then(() => {
                    setFontLoaded(true)
                    setAppIsReady(true);
                })
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn('Fonts are not loaded properly');
                console.log(e)
            }


Update #4: Currently testing

On Expo-Fonts Docs it mentions that you can either use embedded fonts or load at runtime. After reading this, I realized I am currently embedding my fonts and loading them at runtime. I deleted my plugins... fonts from my so I could focus on loading them at runtime. Hopefully this fixes it.

!! I think the embedded and runtime load was my issue. App isn't crashing at all when used in production build !!

I deleted my embedded fonts so I can use the load at runtime. It entailed deleting plugins of fonts.

Do you recall what you did here? Hitting this same issue and like you have tried various options and am still struggling. I can consistently reproduce even in Expo Go but not with reproducible steps. If I simply click around long enough (usually in 5 mins) it will crash and the stackTrace is the same "weightOfFont". I'm now in a similar position to your update 4 in that I'm just embedding and removed all reference to runtime import but still hitting it.

I went the opposite way, I got rid of embedded and went with run time. I was having persistent issues when I embedded it for some reason and the only way I could get working was going with run time.

Seeing something similar with expo-google-fonts/inter - see this github issue https://github.com/expo/google-fonts/issues/109
